# Handling null for char(1) and varcar(2) in hive

Tags: hive, null, hiveql

I am reading a flat file in hive and i have null values coming in file like below

```
a|b|null|null|d
```

and when I create table on top of this with below datatypes

```
a char(1),b char(1),c char(1),varchar2(2),char(1)
```

and the value in table coming like this

```
a,b,n,nu,d
```

The oneway I can do this is to make the datatype as varchar2(4) and add check at null.
But is there any other way i can do this.

Answer (score 1):

SerDe treats 'null' strings as normal values, no difference between value 'a' and 'null'.

Try to add `'serialization.null.format'='null'` property to your table definition:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable SET tblproperties('serialization.null.format'='null');
```

Another approach is to use STRING data type and case statements is select:

```
select case when col = 'null' then null end as col
       ...
```